# JavaScript API post and return using Google Sheets script?

Tags: javascript, json, api, post, google-sheets

I need some help with this. I can't figure out how to print the **return** from an api **post** sent from **Google Sheets** (including any error codes). Posting seems to work fine as the data shows up on **RequestBin** when I run the function in Sheets (although there are no quotes "" around the nonce output, which I don't understand either).

I need to be able to print the return in **Google Sheets** (this function runs in the Script Editor) and the data needs to overflow into adjacent cells, whatever the post request returns.

This is the functional code that I have so far:

```
function testPost() {
  var nonce = new Date().getTime();

  var data = {
    'key':'QrHuXeXcbN',
    'signature':'c4cc0d98be8e0860391799c2ca719da5ea6514f1538c4ec69ec1c19',
    'nonce':nonce
  };

  var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://requestb.in/19bzt9a1', options);
}
```

I have tried a number of different ways to return the values but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Finally. Just needed this at the end... return response.getContentText()

```
function testPost() {
  var nonce = new Date().getTime();

  var data = {
    'key':'QrHuXeXcbN',
    'signature':'c4cc0d98be8e0860391799c2ca719da5ea6514f1538c4ec69ec1c19',
    'nonce':nonce
  };

  var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://requestb.in/19bzt9a1', options);
  return response.getContentText()
}
```